# asp how to handle parameters for all redirects

Tags: asp.net

How do I handle parameters for all redirects?

For example if I'm on my studentinformationpage.aspx and I have a parameters of UserID=Admin&StudentID=Apple.  How do I keep the parameter of userID even when the user leaves that page?

If a user pushes a button for a redirect, they get redirected to admin.aspx but when they go to admin.aspx the user no longer have any parameters.

Comment: If you control access by a parameter in the URL, you need to seriously review your whole application's security.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are doing and how you have architect'd your site, your two main options are storing the userId in a session (using a session variable) so until the user's session expires/log's out the Id will be there; or your could add the query string UserId=Admin&... to the page you are re-directing too.

Have a look here for session sate

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx